# Most efficient way to save / load huge DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feather

I have a single `pd.DataFrame` with 4.3 million rows and 2 columns, like so:

```
Id     Features
27693  [1.6555750043281372e-09, -6.016701912292214e-2...]
27694  [-1.5324687581597672e-32, 1.0946759676292507e-4...]
```

`Features` is a column that stores 512-position `numpy` arrays. I need to have this structure physically stored in my device for loading on-demand, but I am not sure what is the best way to achieve feasible load times. Currently, my solution is to have the `DataFrame` split into 9 equally sized partitions (~500.000 rows) and saved to `feather` files.

Loading these 9 files consistently takes me around `21.609` seconds. Hypothetically, let's say this time-to-load needs to be as fast as it possibly can, while time-to-save isn't an issue.

Are there better formats or techniques to efficiently load large `DataFrames` with `numpy` rows into memory?

Comment: I'd look into using `polars` or `pandas 2.0` I/O will always be a bottle neck unless you can distribute the load.  `Dask` is also a good option.

Comment: @Umar.H interesting, I have tried `Dask` before but never heard of `polars`. Will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your data, if it's binary you could use byteArray.

If not- use numpy arrays and save using pickle.
Save the index and column names separately.

Pandas DF is heavier

Comment: `Features` are originally stored as `bytes` and then converted to `numpy` arrays. Would it be better to do I / O on bytestrings and convert afterwards?

Comment: Depends on your features.  Is it mostly binary? If you have floating numbers you better not.    My previous suggestion was to save the data as numpy arrays and save the index&column names separately. Did you try that? It usually is more efficient in memory than pandas.   Polars should also help

Comment: I ended up partitioning the file using `Dask` and saving features as `Dask` arrays. Afterwards, loading with `glob` naming patterns took only 8 seconds and used half the memory.